# openlayers zoom level image

Tags: openlayers

is there any way adding a transparent logo when you look at a zoom level(maybe after 12. level we dont have layer) which has not baselayer image included in ?

i am using openlayers , arcgis cahce

thank you for your reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi 
i have found a solutions hand of openlayers.

```
OpenLayers.Util.onImageLoadError
```

will help you with you not have baselayer image on your app...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure to understand your needs but:

If you're looking to add a logo after a certain zoom, you could create a layer that only appears from a given zoom with the embedded image in it. Some WMS layer should do the trick.

If you do that because you have nothing to show after level 12, then you should just limit your zoom to a certain amount.

Comment: thanks your reply , i want to add png img (logo) where my baselayer dont have image in it such as after 12 level i want my logo to be seen dublicated everywhere of my map screen